# What is wrong with my SQL Server query as it is not inserting the data in to table

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is my code

```
private void productsavebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAJJAD-PC;Initial Catalog=hotel;Integrated Security=True;");

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        label1.Text = "Connection Successful";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd1.CommandText =( "INSERT INTO product (productname , productprice) VALUES ('" + productnametxtbox.Text + "','" + productpricetxtbox.Text + "')");

        try
        {
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            label1.Text = "Data inserted successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            label1.Text = "Query execution failed";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        label1.Text = "Connection Failed";
    }
}
```

Until connection open it works fine but after that it is not executing the query and it's not even showing any error.

Comment: You can debug/ profile and check if the query is a valid query.

Comment: Do you get an error in Management Studio when you execute this query with a set of values directly?

Comment: Of course it doesn't show any error, you're trapping the exception and only showing *Query execution failed*. Also, let's hope neither `productnametxtbox.Text` nor `productpricetxtbox.Text` contain single quotes.

Comment: As Frederic says, you have to check the message Exception you are getting. And ExecuteNonQuery has a return value. Check it too.

Comment: Put a variable on the exception and append its .message to your query failed message.. so you can see why.. maybe its saying it cant create a duplicate or something

Comment: This is a good example on how code should not be written with respect to SQL Injection...

Comment: @HansLindgren well its my 2nd day on c sharp with sql server, so i dont much about the good coding practices, i will learn eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather change your code to

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SAJJAD-PC;Initial Catalog=hotel;Integrated Security=True;"))
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand()) {
       try {
           cmd1.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO product (productname , productprice) VALUES ('@ProductName', @ProductPrice");
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", productnametxtbox.Text);
           cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", productpricetxtbox.Text);
           cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           label1.Text = String.Format("Error {0}", e.Message);
       }
   }
```

Note that the exceptions now are not swallowing the actual error message but displaying it, and that I'm using parameterized `SQL` to negate SQL Injection.

Comment: thx this code worked after making some edits,but there is a problem that its not picking up the values from text box but saving the values product price and product name, how to save the values that are being written in text boxes ? @3dd

Comment: Remove the ' signs in the VALUES part of the INSERT...